# DASK: Prevent overwrite with NaNs when using mask

Tags: python, dataframe, dask

In Pandas I can use .loc to perform row calculations where a criteria was met, without affecting other rows. Ie, I can isolate row 1, change a columns value, and know that row 2 remains the same.

In Dask, I'm unable to use .loc with the functions I need due to other conflicts (usually "function not implemented", because I've got some complex formulas going on), so I've turned to .mask() as a replacement for .loc()

Using .mask() results in the non-selected rows target column being overwritten with NaN (examples below). Ie, those rows where the condition is met are calculated correctly, but those where the condition is not met any existing values are replaced with NaN. Any further work on the column will leave any earlier calculated rows as NaN.

*

> **What can I use/do do prevent the overwriting of existing values in non-selected rows with NaN?**

- 

Lets start with a sample. 'Coefficient' will always be set to dog.

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd

data = {'a':  [1, 12, 15, 20, 0],
        'b': [1, 10, 15, 20, 10],
    'answer': ['Apple','Orange','Pear', 'Banana', 'Carrot']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['a','b', 'answer'])
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df,npartitions=1)

ddf['Coefficient'] = 'Dog'

#ddf['Coefficient'] = ddf['answer'].mask((ddf['a'] >= 12) & (ddf['b'] > 10))
#ddf['Coefficient'] = ddf['answer'].mask((ddf['a'] >= 12) & (ddf['b'] <= 10))
# Third conditional mask statement
# Fourth Conditional mask statement
# Nth Conditional mask statement


print(ddf.head())
```

Then, lets locate rows using .mask(), and change them to fruit/vegetables based on some criteria

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd

data = {'a':  [1, 12, 15, 20, 0],
        'b': [1, 10, 15, 20, 10],
    'answer': ['Apple','Orange','Pear', 'Banana', 'Carrot']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['a','b', 'answer'])
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df,npartitions=1)

ddf['Coefficient'] = 'Dog'

ddf['Coefficient'] = ddf['answer'].mask((ddf['a'] >= 12) & (ddf['b'] > 10))
ddf['Coefficient'] = ddf['answer'].mask((ddf['a'] >= 12) & (ddf['b'] <= 10))
# Third conditional
# Fourth Conditional
# Nth Conditional

print(ddf.head())
```

This results in:

```
    a   b  answer Coefficient
0   1   1   Apple       Apple
1  12  10  Orange         NaN
2  15  15    Pear        Pear
3  20  20  Banana      Banana
4   0  10  Carrot      Carrot
```

Swapping the two .mask() lines changes the location of the NaN

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd

data = {'a':  [1, 12, 15, 20, 0],
        'b': [1, 10, 15, 20, 10],
    'answer': ['Apple','Orange','Pear', 'Banana', 'Carrot']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['a','b', 'answer'])
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df,npartitions=1)

ddf['Coefficient'] = 'Dog'

ddf['Coefficient'] = ddf['answer'].mask((ddf['a'] >= 12) & (ddf['b'] <= 10))
ddf['Coefficient'] = ddf['answer'].mask((ddf['a'] >= 12) & (ddf['b'] > 10))
# Third conditional
# Fourth Conditional
# Nth Conditional

print(ddf.head())
```

This results in:

```
    a   b  answer Coefficient
0   1   1   Apple       Apple
1  12  10  Orange      Orange
2  15  15    Pear         NaN
3  20  20  Banana         NaN
4   0  10  Carrot      Carrot
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your mask/loc requirement uses information from only one row (so does not use something like `.shift()`), then you can use `df.map_partitions(my_func)`, where `my_func` is defined using `pandas` syntax:

```py
def my_func(df):
    mask_1 = ( df['a']>=12 ) & (df['b']<=10 )
    mask_2 = ( df['a']>=12 ) & (df['b']>10 )
    df.loc[mask_1, 'Coefficient'] = df.loc[mask_1, 'answer']
    df.loc[mask_2, 'Coefficient'] = df.loc[mask_2, 'answer']
    return df

ddf.map_partitions(my_func).compute()
```

Comment: Thanks :) Wont using .compute make this compute the entire data frame? My application includes about 40 calculated columns ad 10 million rows and runs regularly... so I'm hoping to avoid having to compute until as late in the script as possible based on the observation that this tends to make things run much faster. This is still a great example of how to use that function, however, so please leave it intact as an answer.

Comment: Yes, I put the `.compute()` to see the result on the small dataframe, but yes for the real script you don't want to `.compute()` until really needed.